# Sharepoint 2010 CAML Query Person Lookup

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I have a CAML query where I am trying to retrieve records based on the logged in users id.

The following query works on my dev & qa environments, but not in my production environment.  There is data that exists that matches the user.  I have also tested inside SP CAML Query Helper and again there is 0 results returned.

I have tried:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='SharepointUser' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Integer'>37</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>

<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='SharepointUser' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='User'>37</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>

<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='SharepointUser' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Lookup'>37</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

SharepointUser is of Type="User"

Is there some setting that I am missing that I need to set for Lookups to work appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the current user's ID, you should use the [`<UserID/>` CAML element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff625789%28v=office.14%29.aspx), like this:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="SharepointUser" LookupId="TRUE"/><UserID/>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```